# How to force datagridview to reorder rows after change to datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a `List<MyClass>` which is a datasource to a `BindingSource`.  That `BindingSource` is in turn the datasource to my `datagridview`.

When I change a value in my underlying list, and call `datagridview.Refresh()` the change in value is reflected.

However, when I sort my underlying list, the change is NOT reflected in my `datagridview`.  I expect/want the rows in the `datagridview` to be in the order of my underlying list.

I've tried doing a `BindingSource.RestetBindings()` which doesn't work, and has other implications I don't like.

I don't imagine I should be sorting the actual rows in the DGV, but I could be wrong?  It would seem silly to sort the datasource and then have to sort the DGV too.

Comment: It is kludgy, but I have had the same problem in a WPF ListView control. The solution is to set the ItemsSource to null, and then reassign your DataSource. Not elegant, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine:

```
public class Person : IComparable<Person> {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Person other) {
        return Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
    }
}

DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
List<Person> pList = new List<Person>();
BindingSource pSource = new BindingSource();
public MyForm() {
    pList.Add(new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Bob" });
    pList.Add(new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Alan" });
    pSource.DataSource = pList;
    dgv.DataSource = pSource;

    FlowLayoutPanel p = new FlowLayoutPanel { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
    p.Controls.Add(btn);
    p.Controls.Add(dgv);
    Controls.Add(p);
    btn.Click += btn_Click;
}

void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    pList.Sort();
    dgv.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this in my application:  `DataGridView control cannot be sorted if it is bound to an IBindingList that does not support sorting.`.  And it's true, I haven't defined a sort method for my underlying class.

Comment: I can use a lambda expression to order my list, but although the list is reordered (I output to a textbox), it doesn't have an effect on the DGV, even after calling `DGV.Refresh()`.

Comment: I'm not quite there, but using `Sort` on my datasource seems to work.  I don't understand why `Sort` works, but not `OrderBy` - and yes, I am overwriting the original list (as in:  `list = list.OrderBy(....)`

Comment: `OrderBy` creates a new `Enumerable` object, whereas `Sort` is done in place. If you want to use `OrderBy`, then you would have to remove all items from the original list and then add back the items in the new order.

Comment: As I said, when I to `OrderBy` and assign it to the same list (same as in place sort?) it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually what you said, `list = list.OrderBy(...)` makes it seem like you think updating a local variable is going to update the `DataSource` property. If you think something should work, then post a small complete example of code that exhibits the behavior.

Comment: Hmm...  Yes, I guess by reassigning `list = list.OrderBy` I _did_ think that would update the datasource.  My apologies and thanks for the comment and correction.